# how to capture the event of all ajax requests are received

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery. There is a widget based application. There are multiple widgets on single page. 
Every widget contains N number of ajax request while loading the widgets.

How can i capture the event when result of all ajax request are received?  Is there any way without timer?

Comment: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Answer (score 4):

The foolowing jquery method will be called on complete of every ajax request. If you know the number of ajax requests. so you can have a global variable and increment it on every call until it reaches the desired value and then  trigger your desired event

```
var i=0;
$("body").ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings) {
  if(i==MAX_REQ){
    alert("done all");
  }
  else {
    i+=1;
  }
```

});